# When should a Julia project have a Manifest AND Project file?

Tags: julia

I am trying to understand when a Julia Project needs a Manifest AND Project file vs when it just needs a project file. What are the different situations that warrant each case? I am trying to make sure my own project is set up correctly(It has both files currently).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `Manifest.toml` is a snapshot of the exact state of a Julia environment. It specifies all packages that are installed in the environment with version numbers - not just the ones that have been `] add`ed but the entire dependency graph!

The `Project.toml` on the other hand just lists the direct dependencies, that is the packages that have been `] add`ed explicitly, potentially with version bounds specified in a `[compat]` section.

By checking in both files (specifically the `Manifest.toml`), you make your project reproducible. Another user only has to `] instantiate` and will have the exact same environment that you had when working on the project. This is great for **application** projects which might consist of multiple Julia scripts which are not intended for use by other Julia projects.

If you only check in the `Project.toml` you are specifying the dependency information more loosely and will leave room for Julias resolver to find appropriate package versions for all dependencies. This is what you should do when working on a Julia **package** since people will likely want to install your package next to other packages and overly restricting versions of dependencies will make your package incompatible.

Hence, I'd summarize as follows:

> **Application / "Project"** -> Project.toml + Manifest.toml
>
> **Julia Package** -> Only Project.toml

For more on **applications** and **packages** checkout the [glossary](https://julialang.github.io/Pkg.jl/v1/glossary/) of the Pkg.jl documentation.

(Note that there are exceptional cases (unregistered dependencies, for example) where you might have to check in a `Manifest.toml` for a Julia package.)

Comment: Great answer! My team is technically developing a package but it's more so for internal use so I would say we fall under the Project section!

Comment: I'll leave the judgement to you, but just because it's only for internal use doesn't make it less of a package :)

Answer (score 3):

In Julia 1.2 and above, you can have nested `Project.toml` files to express [test-specific dependencies](https://julialang.github.io/Pkg.jl/v1/creating-packages/#Test-specific-dependencies-in-Julia-1.2-and-above-1). Since you may have a `Project.toml` in your `test` folder, which you would need to activate, I would also suggest including a `Manifest.toml`, as a record of under which environment you for-sure know your package's test are passing.

In other words, I believe in the package/application dichotomy mentioned in [crstnbr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58997969), and the recommendation to include `Manifest.toml` with applications, and I would further say that the tests within a package are like an application. The same goes for performance benchmarks that you might have in your package.

I haven't practiced this myself, but it seems like it would be nice to have the CI tests run under both the "frozen" version of the `test/Manifest.toml`, and the latest versions that the package manager can find of each package. If the tests start failing, it would be easier to tease apart whether the breakage is caused by a change in a dependency.